# Script to extract characters from a file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file which looks like this :

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abcd")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("432432")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("32132121")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("321312")
}
```

I want to extract only the ObjectId from the file.

My output should be something like this :

```
abcd
432432
32132121
321312
```

What would be the correct shell script for it if I were to use grep or awk ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this does the job:

```
grep -Po ' ObjectId\("\K[^"]*' file
```

if you love awk:

```
awk -F' ObjectId\\("' '{sub(/".*$/,"",$2)}$0=$2' file
```

Comment: Holy crap... Didn't know `grep` can do this!

Comment: The `awk` gives me only four `0` not sure why. Grep works fine, same does my `awk`

Answer (score 2):

Using sed.

```
sed -n '/ObjectId/ s/.*"\(.*\)")/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

another way you can do it in gawk:

```
gawk 'match($0, /ObjectId\("(.*)"\)/, res) {print res[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\" '/ObjectId/ {print $4}' file
abcd
432432
32132121
321312
```

---

If line has more than one data in the same line you can use this `gnu awk` (Due to RS)

```
cat file
/* 0 */
{
    "tac" : TacID("data") "_id" : ObjectId("abcd")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("432432") "tac" : TacID("data")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("32132121")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("321312")
}
```

```
awk -F\" 'NR>1 {print $2}' RS="ObjectId" file
abcd
432432
32132121
321312
```

---

Another `gnu awk` (Due to `gensub`) That read correct field if multiple field in same line.

```
awk '/ObjectId/ {print gensub(/.*ObjectId[(]"([^"]+).*/,"\\1","g")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/.*ObjectId("\([^"]*\)").*/s//\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/.*\([^"]*\)")/ s//\1/p' YourFile
```

Based on the sample